# IE7 and justify / word wrap css

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, word-wrap, html

i have a page with a sort of tag cloud section on it.
the markup for said cloud is something similar to this..

```
<div class="ContentColumnB">
    <div class="tagcloud">
        <p>
        <span style="font-size: larger;">Office 2010 Issues </span>
        <span style="font-size: x-large;">Windows 7 </span>
        <span>SharePoint </span>
        <span style="font-size: large;">Migration Management Tools</span>
        <span style="font-size: small;">75% Upgrading </span>
        <span style="font-size: smaller;">Desktop Virtualisation</span>
        <span style="font-size: x-large;">Microsoft Jump Start </span>
        <span style="font-size: medium;">Buying Solutions</span>
        <span style="font-size: large;">What-if Planning</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the associated css

```
.ContentColumnB {
height:85px;
padding:5px 10px;
width:460px;
}
.tagcould p{
color:#6192B6 !important;
text-align:justify;
}
div.tagcloud span {
color:#6192B6 !important;
display:inline !important;
padding:0 3px;
word-wrap:break-word;
text-align:inherit;
}
```

as usual I am having problems with IE, IE7 to be precise.
it refuses to split the spans with the style tag onto seperate lines : so **migration management tools** for instance in FF and IE8 the word migration is on one line and the management tools is on the next. for IE 7 however if refuses to stick the latter words on a new line and hence fits a great deal less in the block. this is generated by a WYSIWYG editor, so the solution wont be to change the way the markup is generated.. 
here is what IE looks like : http://www.dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=cgyd1xbpig61kr39kn74.gif

and FF: http://www.dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=iuw5o3cgl5k52m5i1afw.gif

taking the justify off doesnt make any difference to the wrapping either ( i put that in so it at least didnt look all squished over to one side).. **why is it that a span wont run over 2 lines**? clearly im missing something... 
just to confirm that IE8 is ok and of course FF is too.

any suggestions?

thanks

nat

Comment: span always meant for inline text. if you want have multi-line texts, try to use div.

Comment: what about adding <br> for new line ?

Comment: indeed spans are meant for inline content, so why will is it acting like an inline-block or some such. 
cant add a break, as you just want to add text and for it to break in a reasonable manner.. why should you have to add breaks in the middle of a word with a font-size style applied because it refuses to beak on a space ???
seems completely random
if i take the style="font-size:whatever" from the span, it wraps fine.. breaking on the space between the 1st and second word as you would expect.. but with the font style in IE7 it just doesnt..

Comment: Have you tried removing all the styles and adding them back one by one?

Comment: BTW, most of the properties in the `div.tagcloud span` rule don't make sense or are unnecessary. `color:#6192B6` should be inherited from the parent. `span` is already inline so `display:inline` is not needed. And `text-align` doesn't apply to inline elements.

Comment: sure happy to clean up some of the css, but noone seems to be able to explain why it is doing what it is doing.. but noneof the erroneous styles should be affecting the problems i am having ...
in answer to ditch the styles and add in one by one, it all works fine until the span has the style="font-size:whatever" - but as this is what the WYSIWYG kicks out, there is no avoiding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems the problem related to an inherited zoom:1; 
so in order to avoid one IE bug I ran headlong into another

zoom:0 on the span, all is well

nat

Answer (score 0):

You say removing style="font-size:whatever" also removes the problem?

You could run a small javascriptscript replacing the style="font-size:whatever" for something that will accomplish the same visual effect, but not the problem.

Comment: was trying to avoid using js if at all possible..
surely i cant be the only person who has had this problem?